# Identity involving the rising factorial

Tags: special-functions, gamma-function, hypergeometric-function, pochhammer-symbol

I am reading a book about hypergeometric functions and in a proof of a transformation they use the supposedly obvious fact  $$ \displaystyle\frac{(c-a-b)_{n-r}}{(n-r)!} =  \frac{(c-a-b)_{n} (-n)_{r}}{n!\  (1+a+b-c-n)_{r} } $$

I don't see how the two expression are equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is maybe not obvious but doable:

- First note that
  $$\frac{(c-a-b)_{n-r}}{(c-a-b)_n}=\frac{\Gamma(c-a-b+n-r)}{\Gamma(c-a-b+n)}$$
- Next use the reflection formula $\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)=\frac{\pi}{\sin\pi z}$ to write
  $$(1+a+b-c-n)_r\times\frac{\Gamma(c-a-b+n-r)}{\Gamma(c-a-b+n)}=\frac{\sin\pi(c-a-b+n)}{\sin\pi(c-a-b+n-r)}=(-1)^r.$$
- Now it remains to prove that
  $$\frac{(-n)_r(n-r)!}{n!}=(-1)^r,$$
  which is more or less straightforward.

Comment: $$ \frac{(-n)_r(n-r)!}{n!}= \frac{-n(-n+1) \cdots (-n+r-1) (n-r)!}{n!}$$ 

$$=  (-1)^{r} \ \frac{n(n-1) \cdots (n-r+1) (n-r)!}{n!} = (-1)^{r} \frac{n! (n-r)!}{(n-r)! (n!)} = (-1)^{r}$$

Something like that?

Comment: @RandomVariable Exactly that.

Comment: I don't expect authors to explain everything.  But I don't understand the point of so many authors repeatedly using  expressions like "obvious" or "easy to see" or "understandable by lesser life forms."  It serves no purpose. On the other hand, such expressions are used on forums to discourage questions or to feed egos.

Comment: @RandomVariable I agree and I think that most people have the same reading experience. Unfortunately, when they start writing, this is often forgotten.

Answer (score 4):

Using the identity
\begin{align}
(\alpha)_{n-r} = \frac{(-1)^{r} (\alpha)_{n}}{(1-\alpha -n)_{r}}
\end{align}
then it is seen that
\begin{align}
\frac{(c-a-b)_{n-r}}{(n-r)!} = \frac{(c-a-b)_{n-r}}{(1)_{n-r}} = 
\frac{(-1)^{r} (c-a-b)_{n}}{(1-c+a+b-n)_{r}} \cdot \frac{(-n)_{r}}{(-1)^{r} (1)_{n}} = \frac{(c-a-b)_{n} (-n)_{r} }{ n! (1+a+b-c-n)_{r} }.
\end{align}

Comment: Please be more careful so as not to [approve erroneous edits](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/2008094).